# Uninstall java not working?

Tags: java, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall java 1.7.0_10 on ubuntu 12.04 using the instructions from here-http://akbarahmed.com/2012/06/24/uninstall-java-from-ubuntu-linux/. After I complete the instructions, I check for java and it is still there. Any ideas?

Comment: with java you mean ? OpenJDK ? What are the reasons for this ? You want to replace the jre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal window (alt+ctrl+t) and enter the following commands.

`sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/java"`

`sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/java"`

`sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/javaws"`

Then remove the package in the /usr/lib/jvm

This should work!! :)

Comment: on yours, it says 1.7.0_05. Should i change it to 1.7.0_10 because that is what it says it is?

Comment: also, what command do i use to remove the package once i am in the /usr/lib/bin?

Comment: That was quite easy! However, i get an error that says 'this cannot be deleted'. do I need to change permissions?

Comment: oh yeah..i should have guessed that..open a terminal log into root.then type `nautilus /usr/lib/jvm` now try deleting

Comment: Thanks! Now java is deleted, but all of the utilities are still in the dash home. are those tethered to java in any way or just there?

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` in your terminal

Comment: I ran that, but they are still there even after rebooting

Comment: do you see **openjdk-7-java.desktop** in /usr/share/applications. type           `ls /usr/share/applications` in your terminal and check

Comment: I do not see openjdk-7java.desktop, but i do see these:
JB-controlpanel.desktop
JB-java.desktop
 JB-javaws.desktop
 JB-jconsole.desktop
and  JB-policytool.desktop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6886/discussion-between-mukund-and-ikiel2012)